# Can't resolve module after expo update

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I upgraded my app from expo 36 to expo 37 and I have the following error in the web version:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform' in '/xxx/frontend/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet'
```

The android version and the ios version is working properly. The android works in an emulator and on device too.
This is my `package.json` or at least my dependencies:

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.3",
    "expo": "^37.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.13.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.8.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "5.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.22",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/redux": "3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.1.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jest": "25.2.3",
    "jest-expo": "^37.0.0",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^1.13.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },

}
```